How to use Azure OpenAI APIs to programmatically provide editorial review for my MD web pages
I have a few Jekyll websites for smaller open source projects, and wanted to write a local Node.js script, that leverages Azure OpenAI to effectively provide editorial updates to the contents of my web pages (as MD files).
What i want, is to defined prompts for various content elements of the pag that describe what i want done to them (ex psuedo prompt: Here is the page title, optimize for SEO, and limit to 60 characters: "Learn how to get started with development on X". only return the updated title and nothing else.).
I've done this, and sent them off to Azure OpeAI APIs, using the gpt-350-turbo model and the Azure completions API, and I get responses that are close, but they have random "junk" content in there as well (even tho i explicitly specify NOT to in the prompt).
For example, i might get back someting like:
"choices": [
    {
      "text": "Example response (correct):\Get started developing your solution using X\n\n\n\nFor the given",
      "index": 0,
      "finish_reason": "length",
      "logprobs": null
    }

As you can see, it puts "junk" like Example response (correct):\ in front and sometimes weird characters or fragments of "further responses" (like For the given) below.
I assume i'm overlooking something simple; Am i using the wrong model? Is gpt too conversational for simple prompt -> direct output? Is completions the right API?

Provided the possible solution. Check if it works for you. @empire29

Instead of using completion use chat completion where you will provide the sample if on how to give the results.
Here is the sample code.
const { AzureOpenAI } = require("openai");


const endpoint = "https://resourceName.openai.azure.com/";
const apiKey = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
const apiVersion = "2024-04-01-preview";
const deployment = "gpt3t"; //Used gpt-35-turbo model

const prompt =  [
    {
      "role": "user",
      "content": 'Here is the page title, optimize for SEO, and limit to 60 characters: "Learn how to get started with development on X'
    },
    {
        "role":"assistant",
        "content":"Getting Started with Development on X: A Beginner's Guide"
    },
    {
        "role":"user",
        "content":"Optimize the following page title and  limit it to 60 characters, Title is \"Prabhas's Kalki 2898 AD SURPASSES SRK's Jawan, Becomes 4th Highest-Grossing Film Ever In India\"" //Your prompt.
    } 
];

async function main() {

  const client = new AzureOpenAI({ endpoint, apiKey, apiVersion, deployment });  

  const result = await client.chat.completions.create({ messages: prompt, model: deployment, max_tokens: 128 });

  for (const choice of result.choices) {
    console.log(choice.message);
  }
}

main().catch((err) => {
  console.error("Error occurred:", err);
});

module.exports = { main };

Here, i have given the sample input in prompt list. First, as a user and how the output should be in assistant then your original prompt again in user role.
Output:
{
  content: `"Prabhas's Kalki 2898 AD: 4th Highest-Grossing Film in India"`,
  role: 'assistant'
}


Thank you! Using chat API is much better. However the responses sometimes have double quotes around them (as yours does), some times not, sometimes prefixed with strings like “The updated title is:” … I’ve tried prompting as user, assistant and system to say “only return the title with nothing extra” and it sometimes complies, but often does not. How do I get it to always comply? As the variance in response makes it hard for me to programmatically parse.

Please give a custom sentence in assistant content saying to avoid these things.
